# How do I time my sml code?

Tags: smlnj, benchmarking

Can anyone tell me how I can time my sml code?

I have implemented several different versions of the same algorithm and would like to time them and perhaps even know the memoryusage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Timer](http://sml.sourceforge.net/Basis/timer.html) module is what you want. It can either give you cpu time (gives you user, sys and gc times) or wall clock time.

For example of how to use it see the [Benchmark](https://github.com/mortenbp/mylib/blob/master/Other/Benchmark.sml) module of MyLib.

With respect to finding out how much memory your algorithms are using, you might bind the [profiling](http://mlton.org/Profiling) feature of MLton handy. Note however that i have actually never used this, but it [states](http://mlton.org/ProfilingAllocation) that:

> you can profile your program to find out how many bytes each function allocates.

Comment: I have used the MLton profiler a lot, and it's really easy and quite effective.